# Azure Website SQL Connection String and traffic billing

Tags: azure, azure-sql-database

I have noticed that an Azure Website that was created with an associated SQL Azure Database uses a connection string like this:

```
Data Source=tcp:servername.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=sdfdsfsAJQK7ZhHk;User Id=servername@serveradminuser;Password=xxxxxx;
```

I would have expected that the connection string would use some internal hostname of the sql server instead of the public hostname (**servername.database.windows.net** in this case).

Why is this the case and will connection from the website to that host incur traffic charges (I don't think so, but better safe than sorry right)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The SQL Database service is a multi-tenant service, with `servername.data.base.windows.net` as your entry point to the service. There's no other way to get to it.

As for ingress/egress: All services within a region can communicate with each other without any egress metering. This is specifically called out [here](http://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/details/data-transfers/).